# read and output data from string on python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string of data that includes a name of variables and then it comes a value of that variabl.

It may be like that:

```py
string = 'var_name; var_value var_name1; var_value1 var_name2 var_value2 var_name3: var_value3'
```

as you may see it can be separate by `";"` or `":"` or nothing.
How do I create variables and give those variables names and values?
Аll variables may be different and may contain both numbers and letters

I tried to do this using the re library and realized that I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Usually it is a bad idea to create variables dynamically. Store names and values in a dictionary instead. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or another suitable tutorial if not done yet.

Comment: Who designed that string? There is no distinct delimiter, no spacing, so the only thing that seems reasonable you take the position in the strin. You could do `vars=string.replace(";","").replace(":","").split(" ")`.  The resulting `vars` list has variable names in uneven places and the respective values in even places, given that there are no spaces in neithter the variable names nor in the values.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to create variable names. It can be done using either *globals()* or *locals()* as appropriate but it's rarely a good idea to do that.

Better to use a dictionary.

Something like this:

```
string = "var_name; var_value var_name1; var_value1 var_name2 var_value2 var_name3: var_value3"

def pairs(s):
    tokens = s.split()
    for i in range(0, len(tokens), 2):
        yield tokens[i].rstrip(";:"), tokens[i+1]

print(dict(pairs(string)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'var_name': 'var_value', 'var_name1': 'var_value1', 'var_name2': 'var_value2', 'var_name3': 'var_value3'}
```

Comment: this code is good. It will break if there is a space between var name and ":" or ";", though (which is not in the OP costing, but should certainly be expected in such a messy input)

Comment: @jsbueno OP is quite specific about the format of their data. Python variable names cannot include spaces so your argument is moot. I have no idea what you mean by "costing"

Comment: "costing" should have being "posting". Other than that, as I said, your code is fine - my comment is more meant as a warning to the OP in case his input is even further messed than what is listed here.